# Problem with making friends list express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

So, as the title says, I want to make a friends list for my project.
I want users to be able to change their activity status (online, away...).

Each user has a sidebar with all his friends & their activity status (similar to Discord).
I want it to change on every status update.

*Example; I changed my status from Away to Online. My friend who's on the site at the exact same time sees the status change going on his own screen.*

The problem is it's hard to inform every online person from my friends list about the status change, because every time they refresh page/are redirected to another page (still on my site) their socket id is changed.

**I found 2 solutions.**

**I.** Since I use express and I made login system, I could assign a new socket id to an user in some DB on every refresh/redirect. But it would take it from the database **ON EVERY STATUS CHANGE**.

**II.** Make that friends list sidebar an iframe html element. Its source would be an actual friends list. It would make me have my own socket room for ex. (username)-friends ['dragon69-friends'] and every friend of mine will be connected to that room when they're online.

```js
   getFriends().forEach(friend => {
        socket.join(`${friend.username}-friends`)
    });
```

I find them both bad & slow. I might be wrong but it could be laggy with (aiming high) 5k users.
So I am writing this to find a third solution, if not - at least help with choosing better one from these above. As you have probably noticed, English isn't my native, so ask questions if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Option 3, build a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Comment: I can't change it to spa. Looking for 4th solution.